# Writers Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :D

**Note:** This eval will be closing on **27 September 2012**. Get your votes in!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, everyone! :)

Answer (score 3):

[Deciding whether to use a dialogue tag or an action tag in a dialogue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6207/deciding-whether-to-use-a-dialogue-tag-or-an-action-tag-in-a-dialogue)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 3):

[How can I learn how to outline, so I can write like an architect?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/how-can-i-learn-how-to-outline-so-i-can-write-like-an-architect)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Writing a novel which has the same structure and a particular theme in each chapter](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6186/writing-a-novel-which-has-the-same-structure-and-a-particular-theme-in-each-chap)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[What's the significance of ancient mythology in literature?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/whats-the-significance-of-ancient-mythology-in-literature)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[How to know if the events in my novel are 'realistic enough'?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/how-to-know-if-the-events-in-my-novel-are-realistic-enough)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[Synopsis - multiple POVs and time periods](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6181/synopsis-multiple-povs-and-time-periods)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[Is there a technique to help me write this character's notebook entries?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6214/is-there-a-technique-to-help-me-write-this-characters-notebook-entries)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score -1):

[Is it safe to write about a fictional murder in a real-life location?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/is-it-safe-to-write-about-a-fictional-murder-in-a-real-life-location)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score -3):

[What is the word for the action of selecting an item by a mouse?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6197/whats-the-correct-vocabulary-for-a-web-application-tutorial)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score -3):

[Phonetic Dictionary](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/phonetic-dictionary)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.